# Will my Rust character differ if not using family sharing?

Tags: steam, rust, steam-family-sharing

I downloaded Rust from the shared library of a friend. Will my character differ when I buy the game and play it over my own account?

Comment: I removed the vastly unnecessary racism remarks. What you do or do not find attractive has no bearing on the question, it's immaterial. Your prejudices are not welcome - while I understand you don't see it as a problem, others do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In Rust, your character is automatically male, and given a random set of features that is tied to your account. Here's a link to an article that talks about it.

http://steamed.kotaku.com/rust-chooses-players-race-for-them-things-get-messy-1693426299